# How do I get 10 customers that are tied to 4 agents?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one with I have 3 tables:

```
Agents
AgentID AgentEmail

Prospects
ProspectId ProspectMail

AgentProspects
AgentID ProspectID
```

The relationship between the agents and the prospects is done through AgentProspects table.  I know how to join the tables to get a straight froward list of the emails for the agents and their associated prospects but what I want to to now is be able to get a subset of agents and a subset of Prospects associated to each agent.  This would mean if I wanted 2 agents and 10 prospected I would be looking for 20 records returned (10 prospects per agent.)

I tried :

```
select top 10 a.email, pros.email 
from agents a
join agentprospects ap on a.agentid = ap.agentId 
    and a.email in (select top 4 a.email from agents a 
                        group by a.email) 
join prospects pros on ap.prospectId = pros.prospectId
where a.IsDeleted = 0
```

No records where returned.   So what is the best approach to tackling this?

Comment: agents became agent, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.email
      , C.email 
from agent a
       CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT TOP 10 pros.email 
                    FROM AgentProspects AS AP
                    INNER JOIN prospects Pros ON ap.prospectId = pros.prospectId
                    WHERE AP.agentId = a.agentid
                    ) C(email)
where a.IsDeleted = 0 
  and a.agentid IN (1,2)   --<-- two AgentIDs you want results for
```

Comment: nice though in this case I am not looking for a specific agent per say.  It could be any two agents you might get back using a select top 2.  Can this be done without specifying the agent id, perhaps with a subselect in the final in statement vs static ID values?

Comment: I was able to add the sub query to the in statement in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10 a.email, pros.email 
from agent a
join agentprospects ap on a.agentid = ap.agentId 
join prospects pros on ap.prospectId = pros.prospectId
where a.IsDeleted = 0 and
(select count(*) from profile p where a.agentid=ap.agentid) =4
```

Alternatively, you can create function which return scalar (integer) and use it instead subquery from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the top 10 prospects for the top 2 agents.

```
WITH limitedAgents AS
(
    SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Agents
)
SELECT
    a.email
    , p.email
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AgentId ORDER BY ProspectId) as prospectRowNumber
FROM
    limitedAgents a

    JOIN AgentProspects ap
        ON a.agentId = ap.agentId

    JOIN Prospects p
        ON ap.ProspectsId = p.ProspectsId
WHERE
    prospectRowNumber <= 10
```